# Необходимо реализовать ограничение записей в таблицу за текущую дату. Postgres

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть таблица в бд

```sql
CREATE TABLE fio (                  
id serial,                   
user_id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  
first_name TEXT NOT NULL,  
second_name TEXT NOT NULL,                   
age INT NOT NULL,  
date_in date DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE);
```

Заполняется таблица из бота в телеграме.

Запрос на заполнение - (

```
"INSERT INTO fio(user_id, first_name, second_name, age) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)",
(chat_id, first_name, second_name, age))
```

То есть, бот собирает данные о пользователях, для регистрации.

Нужно реализовать ограничение на заполнение 100 пользователей в текущую дату, если число превышено, в бот должен вернуться ответ - "ошибка".

Подскажите, как это лучше сделать, подзапросом или с помощью триггера?

Необходимо самое простое решение. Большое спасибо!

UPD: Запрос найти удалось. Помогите вернуть ошибку, если запись не добавилась, надо как-то получить от БД ответ, что запись не прошла.

Запрос -

```
("INSERT INTO fio (user_id, first_name, second_name, age) 
   SELECT %s,%s,%s,%s WHERE EXISTS (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM fio 
   WHERE date_in = CURRENT_DATE HAVING COUNT(1) < 5);",
(chat_id, first_name, second_name, age)
```

Comment: *Нужно реализовать ограничение на заполнение 100 пользователей в текущую дату* Что такое "пользователь"? В принципе новая запись за текущую дату, даже в случае повторной регистрации?

Comment: С запросом все получилось. Надо вернуть ответ.

Comment: У меня 3 (три) вопроса: 1. Мне кажется, что вопросы не из практики, а из какого-то курса обучения. Тогда надо опираться на пройденный материал, а подсказать могут за рамками этого. 2. А реально именно на БД хочется вешать выполнение таких проверок, как превышение лимита записей за текущую дату? Или может это будет какой-то код на бэкенде делать, до отправки данных в БД? 3. А вот условие нужно именно на текущую дату? Например: правильно ли я понимаю, что ничто не помешает вставить более 100 записей за вчерашнюю дату (например)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просится триггер на вставку данных, но:

1. Вообще-то кажется, что задача какая-то неправильная - прибивать в БД ограничение на число записей на текущую дату.
2. Не оставляет ощущение, что остается лазейка вставки большего числа записей задним числом (за вчера и т.п.)
3. Вообще мне кажется ответ [@Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229437/akina) с констрейном лучше

Ну да ладно, тоже вариант:

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_today_count() RETURNS trigger AS $check_today_count$
    DECLARE
        today_exists    integer;
    BEGIN
        -- Получить число записей за текущую дату
        today_exists = count(id) FROM fio WHERE date_in = CURRENT_DATE;
        -- Выбросить исключение с ошибкой при превышении 100 записей
        IF today_exists >= 100 THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'Error: records limit reached';
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$check_today_count$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER check_today_count BEFORE INSERT ON fio
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_today_count();
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, Дмитрий! Как всегда - очень полезно!

Comment: Я бы все же заменил условие про текущую дату на подсчет числа записей на любую вставляемую дату: today_exists = count(id) FROM fio WHERE date_in = NEW.date_in; - чтобы избежать "хаком" со вставкой большего числа записей задним числом или на будущую дату.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Задача решается созданием пользовательской функции, которая используется в табличном CHECK CONSTRAINT.

### DEMO

```
CREATE TABLE fio (                  
id serial,                   
user_id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  
first_name TEXT NOT NULL,  
second_name TEXT NOT NULL,                   
age INT NOT NULL,  
date_in date DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE);
```

```
CREATE FUNCTION amount_today(OUT amount INT)
AS $$ 
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fio WHERE date_in = CURRENT_DATE
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

```
ALTER TABLE fio ADD CHECK (amount_today() < 3);
```

```
INSERT INTO fio(user_id, first_name, second_name, age) VALUES (1, 'Иван', 'Иванов', 30);
INSERT INTO fio(user_id, first_name, second_name, age) VALUES (8, 'Пётр', 'Петров', 40);
INSERT INTO fio(user_id, first_name, second_name, age) VALUES (23, 'Сидор', 'Сидоров', 25);
```

```
INSERT INTO fio(user_id, first_name, second_name, age) VALUES (41, 'Василий', 'Пупкин', 33);
```

> ```
> ERROR:  new row for relation "fio" violates check constraint "fio_check"
> DETAIL:  Failing row contains (4, 41, Василий, Пупкин, 33, 2023-03-29).
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM fio;
```

| id | user_id | first_name | second_name | age | date_in |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Иван | Иванов | 30 | 2023-03-29 |
| 2 | 8 | Пётр | Петров | 40 | 2023-03-29 |
| 3 | 23 | Сидор | Сидоров | 25 | 2023-03-29 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RqjZX5_4)

Comment: К сожалению, это не работает если вставка делается параллельными транзакциями. Каждая проверит условие и оно пройдет и каждая независимо вставит запись. В результате получим 4 записи.

Comment: Чтоб этот подход заработал, нужно транзакцию выполнять с уровнем изоляции serializable и быть готовым к ложным срабатываниям `could not serialize access` и делать перезапуск транзакции в этом случае.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Да, конечно. Подзапрос же по факту.

Comment: @Akina большое спасибо! Очень помог ваш запрос.

Answer (score 0):

Силами базы данных это просто не сделать. Вероятней всего даже вообще не сделать - без каких-то особых извращений.

Проще перед добавлением записи проверять число записей за текущую дату

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fio WHERE date_in = now()::date
```

и уже получив количество принимать решение - добавлять новую запись или возвращать ошибку

Comment: Запрос, вроде получился, посмотрите, я обновил текст. А вот как вернуть ответ, что запись не была добавлена?

Comment: Как это не сделать? А возбудить исключение в триггере?

Comment: Прошу прощение, Герман. Я вас не понял.